# How to prove this isomorphism of k algebras.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

How can I prove that $$k[x,y]/\langle y-x^2\rangle \simeq k[t]$$ using the homomorphism $\phi(x) = t$ and $\phi(y) = t^2$, where $\phi$ is a k-algebra homomorphism. I mean, $\langle y-x^2 \rangle \subset \ker(\phi)$ is easy, but $\ker(\phi) \subset \langle y-x^2 \rangle$ is hard. I think that I'm missing a important technique here, because there are many examples like this one in algebraic geometry course and I don't know how to approach those problems.

Comment: Do you know division algorithm?

Comment: but im on several variables case

Comment: Treat it as $R[y]$ where $R=k[x]$.

Comment: but I can do euclidian division if R is a field right?

Comment: No, division algorithm works if you wish to divide by a monic polynomial.

Comment: how? do you have a reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could find the inverse of $\phi$. Try $\psi:k[t]\to k[x,y]/\left<y-x^2\right>$
as the $k$-algebra map with $\psi(t)=x$ (or strictly speaking the coset $x+\left<y-x^2\right>$).

Then $\phi(\psi(t))=\phi(x)=t$, $\psi(\phi(x))=\psi(t)=x$ and
$\psi(\phi(y))=\psi(t^2)=x^2$, but $x^2=y$ in the quotient ring
$k[x,y]/\left<y-x^2\right>$. So $\psi$ and $\phi$ are inverses.